# Access a public mapping of mapping of a contract from another contract already published

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, mapping

```
contract Published {

    struct Test {
        uint testData_1;
        uint testData_2;
    }
    
    // address => tokenId => struct
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => Test)) public tests;
}
```

The new contract reads from the already published one.

```
// NEW CONTRACT THAT READS FROM THE PUBLISHED

// Add the getter function to the contract Interface

interface IPublished {
    XXXXX
}

contract New {
    IPublished publishedContract;

    constructor(
        address _publishedContract
    ) {
        publishedContract = IPublished(_publishedContract);
    }

    function getFromMapping(
        address caller,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external returns (IPublished.Test memory test) {

        return publishedContract.tests(caller, tokenId); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this works for me :

```
return publishedContract.tests(caller, tokenId);
```

Basically, for a mapping the getter will accept one parameter, if the value type of the mapping is also a mapping then the getter accepts a second parameter and so on.

You can read more from the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html?highlight=getters#getter-functions) (0.8.10).

Comment: Thanks, I was not finding the documentation around this topic.

Comment: How to do set up the interface of the New in order to access that getter?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? You don't have the interface ? Just knowing the name of the public mapping is enough though

Comment: But you cannot call it from another contract without its interface type